# HTML variable into python variable

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-2.7, xhtml

I don't have mach experience with html so I hope to use the right terminology to explain myself.

I have the following html line ..

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
             var graph_raw_data = [{"parent_id": 844, "process_id": 236, "process_name":    "C0nw0nk Steam Patcher.exe","first_seen":
       "2355-02-21 00:00:00,183", "calls": [{"category": "system",
       "timestamp": "2355-02-21 00:00:00,193", "api": "LdrGetDllHandle"},
       {"category": "process", "timestamp": "2015-02-21 18:59:49,584",
       "api": "ExitProcess"}]}];
  </script>
```

this node is nested within few nodes with the following pattern:

```
<div class="tab-content">
```

How can i inject graph_raw_data into **python** variable - something slimier to dictionary varibale type.

Basically I need to iterate thorough all the nodes and find the desire one ?
how can I do it in **python** ?

I take the html data with this python code:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page_data = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_data)
```

Comment: HTML is just markup, it does not have any variables :-(

Comment: `graph_raw_data` is a JavaScript object, nicely decorated as JSON. Use Python to parse the JSON. How that works, I don't know, but JSON is there to allow us to send data between languages.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to extract the string which contains the variable, then use `json.loads` to convert it into python variable.

```
import json
import re

html="""<script type="text/javascript">
             var graph_raw_data = [{"parent_id": 844, "process_id": 236, "process_name":    "C0nw0nk Steam Patcher.exe","first_seen":
       "2355-02-21 00:00:00,183", "calls": [{"category": "system",
       "timestamp": "2355-02-21 00:00:00,193", "api": "LdrGetDllHandle"},
       {"category": "process", "timestamp": "2015-02-21 18:59:49,584",
       "api": "ExitProcess"}]}];
  </script>"""

graph_raw_data=re.search(r'var graph_raw_data = (.*?);',html.replace('\n','')).group(1)
data=json.loads(graph_raw_data)
print(data)
>>>[{'parent_id': 844, 'calls': [{'timestamp': '2355-02-21 00:00:00,193', 'category': 'system', 'api': 'LdrGetDllHandle'}, {'timestamp': '2015-02-21 18:59:49,584', 'category': 'process', 'api': 'ExitProcess'}], 'process_name': 'C0nw0nk Steam Patcher.exe', 'first_seen': '2355-02-21 00:00:00,183', 'process_id': 236}]
```